# Add item to dictionary (array inside of a dictonary?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```py
dic = {"t": [{"x": 0}, {"x": 1}, {"x": 2}]}

print(dic)
dic["t"] = dic["t"].append({"x": 3})
print(dic)
```

Actual result: `{'t': None}`

Wanted result: `{'t': [{'x': 0}, {'x': 1}, {'x': 2}, {"x": 3}]}`

Is probably simple I just do not really know what to search for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `append` method is **in place**, it does not output anything (well, it outputs `None`). When you run `dic["t"] = dic["t"].append({"x": 3})`, you replace the initial list with None.

You need to do:

```
dic["t"].append({"x": 3})
```

Full code:

```
dic = {"t": [{"x": 0}, {"x": 1}, {"x": 2}]}
print(dic)
dic["t"].append({"x": 3})
print(dic)
```

output:

```
{'t': [{'x': 0}, {'x': 1}, {'x': 2}]}
{'t': [{'x': 0}, {'x': 1}, {'x': 2}, {'x': 3}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

`append()` returns `None` and not the list on which you apply the method as you expect. Change:

```
dic["t"] = dic["t"].append({"x": 3})
```

To:

```
dic["t"].append({"x": 3})
```

Another option is to do the following:

```
dic = {"t": [{"x": 0}, {"x": 1}, {"x": 2}]}

print(dic)
dic["t"] += [{"x": 3}]
print(dic)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing only `dic["t"].append({"x":3})` because `append` updates the list but returns `None` so your new value will be `None`. Instead, just update the value.